# (react admin) How do I upload images in binary format?

Tags: file-upload, react-admin

I usually use axios and postman to upload images and they work without extra configuration.
I just append the image file to the form data and send it and the server detects it correctly and saves it.
However with react admin, I get it in raw format and if I try uploading it then the server doesn't detect it correctly.
How do I make react admin upload images without messing with them.
I simply want to upload the image in the same format that fetch or axios use.
When I check the network tool in chrome, using axios, the file field is of type binary however react admin shows an object that has a rawFile field and if i try to send the rawfile field then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my DatProvider it is done like this:

```
case CREATE:
  options.method = 'POST'
  
  if (resource === 'photos') {
    const { file, ...model } = params.data
    let form = new FormData()

    if (file && file.rawFile) {
      form.append('file', file.rawFile) 
    }
  
    options.body = form
  }
```